# Query optimisation (Using joins instead subquery)?

Tags: sql

I need help with this query. I need to improve execution time of query. Any sugestions how to improve and optimise it? I think that subquery is the most problematic part of it. Any idea how to change it and make it faster?

```
select pro.ID,lt.TASK_ID,lt.ACTIVITY_NAME, lt.CREATION_TIME as START_TIME, lt.END_TIME, lum.USERNAME, to_char((lt.END_TIME-lt.CREATION_TIME),'dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mm:ss')  AS TASK_DURATION
 from pdw_lsw_tracking_point tp, pdw_lsw_tracking_point_value tpv, pdw_tg_processtable pro, pdw_lsw_task lt, pdw_lsw_user_mappings lum
 where  tp.tracking_point_id=tpv.tracking_point_id
and pro.task_id = tpv.task_id
and lt.functional_task_id=tpv.task_id
and lt.SYSTEM_USER_ID = TO_CHAR(lum.USER_ID) AND lt.SYSTEM_ID = lum.SYSTEM_ID
and tp.TRACKING_GROUP_ID=tpv.TRACKING_GROUP_ID
and pro.ID IN (select pro.ID  from  pdw_tg_processtable pro where step=13 and time_stamp between  '01.03.21' and  '08.03.21')
group by pro.ID,lt.TASK_ID,lt.ACTIVITY_NAME, lt.CREATION_TIME, lt.END_TIME, lum.USERNAME
order by pro.ID,lt.CREATION_TIME;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Why do you use 1980s style comma-separated joins? Is the query that old? Why `TO_CHAR` on `USER_ID`? Is the data type for `USER_ID` different from table to table? Any chance to get this fixed in the data model?

Comment: The format `'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mm:ss'` looks weird for a duration. And why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggragtion function? Do you want to get distinct rows (for which we'd prefer `SELECT DISTINCT`)? Why then are the rows not distinct in the first place? Is any of the joins creating duplicates? Removing duplicates is a costly operation.

Comment: You have the table `pdw_lsw_tracking_point_value` twice in your query. Once as `tp`, once as `tpv`. Why? You don't seem to be using any of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
select pro.ID, lt.TASK_ID, lt.ACTIVITY_NAME, lt.CREATION_TIME as START_TIME, lt.END_TIME, lum.USERNAME, to_char((lt.END_TIME-lt.CREATION_TIME),'dd.MM.yyyy HH24:mm:ss')  AS TASK_DURATION
from pdw_lsw_tracking_point tp, 
JOIN pdw_lsw_tracking_point_value as tpv ON tp.tracking_point_id=tpv.tracking_point_id
JOIN pdw_tg_processtable as pro ON pro.task_id = tpv.task_id
JOIN pdw_lsw_task as lt ON lt.functional_task_id=tpv.task_id
JOIN pdw_lsw_user_mappings as lum ON lum.SYSTEM_ID = lt.SYSTEM_ID 
where lt.SYSTEM_USER_ID = TO_CHAR(lum.USER_ID) 
and tp.TRACKING_GROUP_ID=tpv.TRACKING_GROUP_ID
and pro.ID IN (select pro.ID  from  pdw_tg_processtable pro where step=13 and time_stamp between  '01.03.21' and  '08.03.21')
group by pro.ID,lt.TASK_ID,lt.ACTIVITY_NAME, lt.CREATION_TIME, lt.END_TIME, lum.USERNAME
order by pro.ID,lt.CREATION_TIME;
```

Comment: It is good you re-wrote the query from outdated comma joins to proper explicit joins. But how does your query improve execution time?

Comment: This join will also improve execution time.

Comment: This is very unlikely. It's just an alternative syntax for the same thing. I don't know any DBMS that performs worse when using 1980s comma-separated joins. Their disadvantage is not lack of speed, but decreased readability, proneness to errors and lack of outer join support. We shouldn't use that old syntax anymore, but we don't gain runtime speed thus.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an ancient join syntax for no apparant reason. The first thing to do would be to clean this up and use proper joins (`INNER JOIN ... ON`) as have been introduced in standard SQL of 1992.

Then there are three things that immediately catch one's attention:

1. Sometimes you use `TO_CHAR` on `user_id`, sometimes not. This column should be stored identically (i.e. with the same data type) in the various tables. If this is not the case, access can get extremely slow, because indexes might probably not be used.
2. You `GROUP BY` without using aggregation functions. That means you `SELECT DISTINCT`, only a bit obfuscated. This brings the question up: why must you remove duplicates? How do they come into existence? Do you maybe produce them yourself with inappropriate joins? Working with too large intermediate results and removing duplicates later is a costly operation.
3. A column called `id` should be the table's primary key. So why would you use a subquery to select the IDs only to select from the same table again based on the IDs? You'll get the exact same rows. Just apply the criteria directly.

On a closer look we see that you have the table `pdw_lsw_tracking_point_value` twice in your query, but you are not really using it. The `tpv` gets joined on `task_id` to link `pro` and `lt`, but you could just as well join `pro` and `lt` on `task_id` directly. The `tp` gets joined on `tracking_point_id` and `tracking_group_id`, but then `tp` is not used anymore.

With `user_id` data types fixed, you get something along the lines of:

```
select 
  pro.id,
  lt.task_id,
  lt.activity_name,
  lt.creation_time as start_time,
  lt.end_time,
  lum.username,
  lt.end_time - lt.creation_time as task_duration
from pdw_tg_processtable pro 
join pdw_lsw_task lt on lt.functional_task_id = pro.task_id
join pdw_lsw_user_mappings lum on lum.system_id = lt.system_id
                              and lum.user_id = lt.system_user_id
where pro.step = 13 and pro.time_stamp between date '2021-03-01' and date '2021-03-21'
order by pro.id, lt.creation_time;
```

You want these indexes:

```
create idx1 on pdw_tg_processtable (step, time_stamp, task_id, id);
create idx2 on pdw_tg_processtable (time_stamp, step, task_id, id);
create idx3 on pdw_lsw_task (functional_task_id, system_id, system_user_id);
create idx4 on pdw_lsw_user_mappings (system_id, system_user_id, username);
create idx5 on pdw_lsw_user_mappings (system_user_id, system_id, username);
```

(Of these you only need either idx1 or idx2 and either idx4 or idx5. I don't know which, though. Create them all and drop the unused ones later.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your subquery:

```
and exists
 (select pt.ID
    from pdw_tg_processtable pt
   where step=13
     and time_stamp between '01.03.21' and '08.03.21'
     and pt.id = pro.ID)
```

Comment: Why do you think `EXISTS` is faster than `IN`? They do the same thing and a good optimizer should come up with the same execution plan for both.

Comment: It is not the exists part what is important but the pt.id = pro.ID part. I think the query will be faster if an index exists for the pro.ID column.

Comment: It shouldn't.`where pro.id in (select pt.id ...)` does exactly the same as `where exists (select ... where pt.id = pro.id)`. But well, the OP hasn't told us their DBMS. Maybe, just maybe, it does have problems with `IN` :-) Early MySQL versions did sometimes.